# Odoo Warning - Missing Record : Record does not exist or has been deleted

Tags: python, odoo-10

I'm trying to create record into document.propose.in model. However, I got the warning when I clicked on data_create button. I've tried to check where the code goes wrong, and it's the code in this line:

```
message_obj.create({
                'res_id': self.ids[0],
                'model': 'document.propose.in',
                'subtype_id': subtype_id,
                'body': _('Changes in the document %s has been approved by QMR.') % self.name
                })
```

There's no error information showed in terminal. It does, however, showed in the browser's console.

> web.assets_common.js:3023 Server application error {"message":"Odoo Server Error","code":200,"data":{"debug":"Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/odoo10/odoo/http.py\", line 640, in _handle_exception\n    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)\n  File \"/home/odoo10/odoo/http.py\", line 677, in dispatch\n    result = self._call_function(**self.params)\n  File \"/home/odoo10/odoo/http.py\", line 333, in _call_function\n    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/home/odoo10/odoo/service/model.py\", line 101, in wrapper\n    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/home/odoo10/odoo/http.py\", line 326, in checked_call\n    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)\n  File \"/home/odoo10/odoo/http.py\", line 935, in **call**\n    return self.method(*args, **kw)\n  File \"/home/odoo10/odoo/http.py\", line 506, in response_wrap\n    response = f(*args, **kw)\n  File \"/home/odoo10/addons/web/controllers/main.py\", line 889, in call_button\n    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})\n  File \"/home/odoo10/addons/web/controllers/main.py\", line 877, in _call_kw\n    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)\n  File \"/home/odoo10/odoo/api.py\", line 689, in call_kw\n    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)\n  File \"/home/odoo10/odoo/api.py\", line 680, in call_kw_multi\n    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/home/innotek4/Documents/ISO/odoo_komp/mgmt_documents/wizards/document_register.py\", line 113, in data_create\n    'body': _('Changes in the document %s has been approved by QMR.') % self.name\n  File \"/home/odoo10/addons/mail/models/mail_message.py\", line 724, in create\n    values['record_name'] = self._get_record_name(values)\n  File \"/home/odoo10/addons/mail/models/mail_message.py\", line 680, in _get_record_name\n    return self.env[model].sudo().browse(res_id).name_get()[0][1]\n  File \"/home/odoo10/odoo/models.py\", line 1546, in name_get\n    result.append((record.id, convert(record[name], record)))\n  File \"/home/odoo10/odoo/models.py\", line 5211, in **getitem**\n    return self._fields[key].**get**(self, type(self))\n  File \"/home/odoo10/odoo/fields.py\", line 913, in **get**\n    value = record._cache[self]\n  File \"/home/odoo10/odoo/models.py\", line 5563, in **getitem**\n    return value.get() if isinstance(value, SpecialValue) else value\n  File \"/home/odoo10/odoo/fields.py\", line 48, in get\n    raise self.exception\nMissingError: (u'Record does not exist or has been deleted.', None)\n","exception_type":"missing_error","message":"Record does not exist or has been deleted.\nNone","name":"odoo.exceptions.MissingError","arguments":["Record does not exist or has been deleted.",null]}}

Line 113 is where the function create message_obj. I've tried updating module, but no luck. Here's the code (in case it's gonna help):

```
class documentregister(models.TransientModel):
_name = "document.register"
_description = "document register"

name = fields.Char('Title', required=True)
type = fields.Selection(
    [('content', 'Content'), ('category', 'Category')],
    'Type',
    help="Page type",
    default="content"
)
act = fields.Selection(
    [('create', 'Create'), ('edit', 'Edit')],
    'Action'
)
parent_id = fields.Many2one(
    'document.page',
    'Category',
    domain=[('type', '=', 'category')]
)
doc_page = fields.Many2one('document.page','Document')
content = fields.Text("Content")
revision = fields.Integer('Revision', default=0)
doc_no = fields.Char('Document Number')
dept = fields.Many2one('hr.department', 'Department',domain=[('parent_id', '=', False)])
section = fields.Many2one('hr.department','Section')
id_dpi = fields.Many2one('document.propose.in', 'id_dpi')
document_attc1 = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='ir.attachment', relation='document_propose_attachment_wiz', string="Add Attachment")
issue_plan = fields.Date('Document Issue Plan')
distribution_ids = fields.One2many('document.distribusi.regis', 'doc_id', 'Distribution Dept')

@api.multi
def data_create(self):
    if self.act =="create":
        if self.content:
            document_page_obj = self.env['document.page']
            masterdist=[]
            for di in self.id_dpi.distribusi_ids:
                masterdist2=(0, 0, {'dept':di.dept.id})
                masterdist.append(masterdis2)
            id_create = document_page_obj.create(
                {'name': self.name,
                 'type': 'content',
                 'dept': self.dept.id,
                 'section': self.section.id,
                 'doc_no': self.doc_no,
                 'content': self.content,
                 'parent_id': self.parent_id.id,
                 'write_uid': self.env.uid,
                 'write_date': time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                 'distribusi_ids': masterdist,
                 }
            )
            document_page_history_obj = self.env['document.page.history']
            dph_ids_list = document_page_history_obj.search([('page_id', '=', id_create.id)])
            dph_ids_list.sorted(key=lambda r: r.id)
            attach = []
            for att in self.document_attc1:
                attach.append(att.id)
            dph_ids_list.write({'date_confirm': self.issue_plan,'lamp':[(6, 0,attach)]})
            id_create.page_approval_approved2()
            id_create.distribusi_act()
            document_page_in_obj = self.env['document.propose.in']
            model_data_obj = self.env['ir.model.data']
            message_obj = self.env['mail.message']
            subtype_id = model_data_obj.get_object_reference('mail', 'mt_comment')[1]
            message_obj.create({
                'res_id': self.ids[0],
                'model': 'document.propose.in',
                'subtype_id': subtype_id,
                'body': _('Changes in the document %s has been approved by QMR.') % self.name
                })
            return self.id_dpi.write({'date_limit': time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),'confirm_id': self.env.uid,'propose_id_new': id_create.id,'state': 'convert','doc_regis_bool':True})
        else:
            raise osv.except_osv(_('Invalid Action!'), _('Please Entry Content Document First!'))

    elif self.act=="edit":
        if self.content:
            document_page_obj = self.env['document.page']
            dp_ids=document_page_obj.search([('id', '=',self.doc_page.id)])[0]
            masterdist = []
            for di in self.id_dpi.distribusi_ids:
                masterdist2 = (0, 0, {'dept': di.dept.id})
                masterdist.append(masterdist2)
            vals={'name': self.name,
                 'dept': self.dept.id,
                 'section': self.section.id,
                 'doc_no': self.doc_no,
                 'content': self.content,
                 'parent_id': self.parent_id.id,
                 }
            dp_ids.write(vals)
            document_distribution_master_obj = self.env['document.distribution.master']
            ddm_ids = document_distribution_master_obj.search([('doc_id_master', '=', self.doc_page.id)]).unlink()
            dp_ids.write({
                 'distribution_ids': masterdist,
                 })
            document_page_history_obj = self.env['document.page.history']
            dph_ids_list=dp_ids.create_history(self.doc_page.id, self.content, "content", self.doc_no, revision=self.revision)
            distribution = dp_ids.create_distributionmaster_revision_2(dph_ids_list.id,self.id_dpi.distribution_ids)
            attach = []
            for att in self.document_attc1:
                attach.append(att.id)
            dph_ids_list.write({'date_confirm': self.issue_plan, 'lamp': [(6, 0, attach)]})
            dp_ids.page_approval_approved2()
            dp_ids.distribusi_act()
            document_page_in_obj = self.env['document.propose.in']
            model_data_obj = self.env['ir.model.data']
            message_obj = self.env['mail.message']
            subtype_id = model_data_obj.get_object_reference('mail', 'mt_comment')[1]
            message_obj.create(
                {'res_id': self.id_dpi.id,
                 'model': 'document.propose.in',
                 'subtype_id': subtype_id,
                 'body': _('Changes in the document %s has been approved by QMR.') % self.name
                 }
            )
            return self.id_dpi.write({'date_limit': time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),'confirm_id': self.env.uid,'state': 'convert','doc_regis_bool':True})
        else:
            raise osv.except_osv(_('Invalid Action!'), _('Please Entry Content Document First!'))
```

Comment: 'subtype_id': subtype_id.id ?

Comment: @TadeuszKarpinski have tried that. not working. subtype_id is the correct form.

Comment: @AxelMendoza it works. I didn't even think about that possibility. thank you!

Comment: Please I put it in an answer so you could vote it. It helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'res_id': self.ids[0], or 'res_id': self.id_dpi.id,? the last seems to be ok.

Use this code:

```
message_obj.create({
    'res_id': self.id_dpi.id,
    'model': 'document.propose.in',
    'subtype_id': subtype_id,
    'body': _('Changes in the document %s has been approved by QMR.') % self.name
})
```